# Not able to close iframe on button click

Tags: javascript, iframe

Hi I have an image and on click of that image it calls another .aspx page which loaded as an iframe. I want on click of button inside an iframe it close the iframe. I tried differnt methods but none of them is working:

Here is my iframe:

```
function openBox() {
    $(".nodeOption, .nodeOptionBlack").fadeIn(200);
    var pageHeight = $(document).height();
    var pageWidth = $(document).width();
    $(".nodeOptionBlack").css("height", pageHeight).css("width", pageWidth);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nodeOptionBlack").click(function () {
        $(".nodeOption, .nodeOptionBlack").fadeOut(200);
    });

    $(".WindowClose").click(function () {
        $(".nodeOption, .nodeOptionBlack").fadeOut(200);
    });

Here is my function of button click:

function Submit_Click() {
    var enroll = test();
    if (enroll == "sale") {
        a.Node(urlParams["parentid"], urlParams["placement"], 1, "Sale");
    }
    else {
        a.Node(urlParams["parentid"], urlParams["placement"], 1, "");
    }

//here i want to close my iframe 
}

i tried different things like:

  $("#nodeOption").remove();
  window.parent.closeIframe();

      //document.getElementById("nodeOption").parent.removeChild(iframe);
     //$('#nodeOption', top.document).dialog('close');
     // window.parent.closeIframe();
    //$(".nodeOption, .nodeOptionBlack").fadeOut(200);

function closeIframe() {
    alert("hi");
    var ifram = document.getElementById(".nodeOption");
    iframe.parent.removeChild(iframe);
}
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.Thanks!

Comment: iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe); not working and ya i fixed var iframe=.. but it never calls this fuction on window.parent.closeIframe();

Comment: I edited my answer, along with the live demo.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Since you are using jQuery, use the `.remove()` method of the element. Here we get the iframe with the id "iframe" and remove it off the body, on the click of any `button` element:

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
/* This part is the put the button inside the iframe,
   it's not related to your problem */

$('#iframe').contents().find('body').append('<button>Click Here</button>');

/* We seek for a `button` element within the iframe body, in the iframe content */
$('#iframe').contents().find('body button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe').remove();
    $('#result').text('Iframe deleted!');
});
```

Oh and **trust me**, you don't want to do this in Pure JavaScript (Everything's easy until you try to get the ownerDocument of the iframe to delete the iframe element itself).

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bawpK/6)*(updated)*

Comment: Thanks but my button is inside the iframe does it matter

Comment: @user207888 I will update my code according to your needs in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help, my issue got resolved. Here what I did:

In my iframe on button click I call

```
 window.parent.closeIframe1();
```

and on parent page I code:

```
  function closeIframe1()
        {
            $(".nodeOption, .nodeOptionBlack").fadeOut(200);
            return false;
        }
```

and it worked fine for me.